# Skip building wheel if it's already in the wheelhouse

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I'm automatically building wheels for each tagged release using github URL. These wheels are then uploaded to a wheelhouse.

Command I'm using is

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=/tmp/wheels/                             \
          --find-links=http://wheelhouse/index.html            \
          git+ssh://git@github.com/company/project.git@1.2.3
```

`/tmp/wheels/` is initially empty.

This rebuilds, even if the wheel for the release `1.2.3` of the `project` is already in the remote wheelhouse. Short of downloading all the wheels from the wheelhouse into local wheel dir, is there any other way of preventing unnecessary rebuilding?

Comment: Since you explicitly specify the version number, why not just check if the version already exists in the wheelhouse before calling `pip wheel` on it?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan I would need to know the name of the wheel, which might not match the github name (for example `http://github.com/datastax/python-driver@3.7.1` builds wheel `cassandra-driver-3.71`). Assuming I'd get that from the `setup.py`, I'd still need to do that with a script. More moving parts, more prone to breaking.

Comment: I believe this is [an open issue on the `pip` issuetracker](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/855). Until that gets resolved, I don't believe you have much of a choice. Just maintain a local mapping of URL to wheel name in `script.py` or somewhere else, and check against that.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan you're right. I hoped from some kind of workaround, but it might as well not be possible w/o doing this check myself